# LWC Table column dynamic style

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

[image]

I need to dynamically `add` or `remove` colors based on the data returned by Apex

It's July, so all months after July need to show colors. Colors do not need to be displayed before July.

please ignore `showColor` & `noShowColor`

what should I do?

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <table class="slds-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>M1</th>
                <th>M2</th>
                <th>M3</th>
                <th>M4</th>
                <th>M5</th>
                <th>M6</th>
                <th>M7</th>
                <th>M8</th>
                <th>M9</th>
                <th>M10</th>
                <th>M11</th>
                <th>M12</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <template for:each={data} for:item="item">
                <tr key={item.idx}>
                    <td class={noShowColor}>{item.M1}</td>
                    <td class={noShowColor}>{item.M2}</td>
                    <td class={noShowColor}>{item.M3}</td>
                    <td class={noShowColor}>{item.M4}</td>
                    <td class={noShowColor}>{item.M5}</td>
                    <td class={noShowColor}>{item.M6}</td>
                    <td class={noShowColor}>{item.M7}</td>
                    <td class={showColor}>{item.M8}</td>
                    <td class={showColor}>{item.M9}</td>
                    <td class={showColor}>{item.M10}</td>
                    <td class={showColor}>{item.M11}</td>
                    <td class={showColor}>{item.M12}</td>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  showColor = 'slds-is-edited';
  noShowColor = '';
  data = [
    {"M1":"$100","M2":"$101","M3":"$103","M4":"$100","M5":"$104","M6":"$100","M7":"$100","M8":"$100","M9":"$100","M10":"$100","M11":"$100","M12":"$100"},
    {"M1":"$100","M2":"$103","M3":"$103","M4":"$102","M5":"$104","M6":"$102","M7":"$103","M8":"$104","M9":"$101","M10":"$101","M11":"$102","M12":"$103"},
    {"M1":"$101","M2":"$101","M3":"$102","M4":"$100","M5":"$101","M6":"$100","M7":"$100","M8":"$100","M9":"$100","M10":"$100","M11":"$100","M12":"$100"},
  ];
}
```

[Studio Webcomponents](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/vY22YY6y02YzpjNYL41x/src/app.js?p=stories)

Comment: You need to add another attribute in that represent class in JSON like: ,{"M1":"$100", "M1_status":"slds-is-edited","M2":"$20", "M2_status":"",....`, then you can use status class field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set extra properties, as Raul said. Further, you can use lightning-datatable to do this, and you'll get extra capabilities if you need it. I transformed your example into a lightning-datatable, and demonstrate how to set the properties per cell.

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
import getDataExample from 'c/utils';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  showColor = 'slds-is-edited';
  noShowColor = '';
  columns = [...Array(12).keys()]
    .map((_,i)=>
      ({ 
        hideDefaultActions: true, 
        fieldName: `M${i+1}`, 
        label: `M${i+1}`, 
        cellAttributes: { 
          class: {
            fieldName: `M${i+1}_style`
          }
        }
      })
    )
  data = [];
  @wire(getDataExample) handleData({data,error}) {
    if(!data) {
      return;
    }
    // Example of calculating the new styles
    this.data = data
      .map(row => Object.fromEntries( // Construct object from [[key1,value1],[key2,value2],...]
        Object.entries(row) // Deconstruct to [[key1,value1],...] nested array
          .map((entry, index) => // Convert [key1,value1] to [[key1,value1],[key2,value2]],...]
            [entry, 
              [`${entry[0]}_style`, 
                index < 8? this.noShowColor: this.showColor
              ]
            ]
        ).flat(1) // Convert [[[key1,value1],[key2,value2]],...] to [[key1,value1],[key2,valu2],...]
      )
    )
  }
}
```